# How to create Cusom SSL socket factory using http cpmonent 4.5.2

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I found below example to create custom socket factory using commons-httpclient 3.1

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java

Same way how can i create custom SSL socket factory to validate certificate in http-component 4.5.2